# Web3.py error: Unsupported type: the primitive argument must be one of: bytes,bytearray

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain, web3.py

I am trying to deploy a contract to a private Ethereum chain following instructions from [here](https://medium.com/@rangersz2018/setting-a-multi-node-private-ethereum-blockchain-with-proof-of-authority-a804fec4b1c3) and using following code. I have used this same code several times with Ropsten and it worked perfectly but now it is giving following error.

`Unsupported type: The primitive argument must be one of: bytes,bytearray, int or bool and not str`

Please help me, where I am making mistake.

```
 import web3,time from datetime import datetime from solc import compile_source from web3 import Web3,HTTPProvider from web3.contract import ConciseContract from eth_account import Account import csv,random,sys from web3.auto import w3 import binascii number_of_files=0;


def deploy_contract(compiled_sol):


    print('Deploying contract ..')
    contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://192.168.122.31:8543'))
    if(w3.isConnected()):
        print('we are connected!')
    else:
       print('Sorry not connnected!')
    # w3.eth.enable_unaudited_features()
    account = Account()
    acct = account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key)

    contract_ = w3.eth.contract(abi = contract_interface['abi'], bytecode = contract_interface['bin'])
    print('We have done this  ',contract_)
    print(acct.address)
    unlocked = w3.geth.personal.unlock_account(acct.address,"xx")

    contract_data = contract_.constructor().buildTransaction({
            'from': acct.address,
            'gas': 1728712,
            'gasPrice':w3.toWei('21','gwei'),
            'chainId': 5333
        })


    print('Transaction built ....')
    contract_data['to']=""

    trans_hash = w3.eth.sendTransaction(contract_data)
    time_transaction_sent = datetime.now()
    receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(trans_hash.hex())

    time_receipt_recieved = datetime.now()
    block_n = receipt['blockNumber']
    gas_used = receipt['gasUsed']
    contract_address = receipt['contractAddress'] contract_code = 

pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

contract SimpleStorage {
    string source_address;
    string dest_address;
    uint protocol;
    constructor() public {
        field_one = '';
        field_two = '';
        field_three = 0;
    }
    function set_params (string field_one, string field_two, uint field_three) public {
        field_one=field_one;
        field_two=field_two;
        field_three=field_three;
    }

    function get_field_one() public returns (string) {
        return field_one;
    }
    function get_field_two() public returns (string) {
        return field_two;
    }
    function get_field_three() public returns (uint) {
        return field_three;
    }
    function get_time_stamp() public returns (uint256){
        return now;
    } }

try:
    compiled_sol = compile_source(contract_code)
    time_compilation_ended = datetime.now()
    print('compiled source ..')
    deploy_contract(compiled_sol) except Exception as e:
    print(e, 'Error in contract code') ``
```

Comment: Did you find a solution on this?

Comment: try to change your transaction hex. It must be in `str` datatype

Answer (score 1):

In my case,the problem was the `bytecode` was empty, so it was being pass an empty string which was not being properly encoded. So to fix it I changed it to `this_contract = self.w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytes(bytecode.encode()))` like this:

```
   this_contract = self.w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytes(bytecode.encode()))
    tx={
            "ch this_contract = self.w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytes(bytecode.encode()))
   
    tx={
            "chainId": self.w3.eth.chain_id,
            "gasPrice": int(self.w3.eth.gas_price),
            "from": self.account.address,
            "nonce": self.w3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.account.address),
        }
    print(tx)
    transaction = this_contract.constructor().buildTransaction(
        tx
    )
  
    signed_txn = self.w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=self.account.key)
    print("Deploying Contract!")
    # Send it!
    tx_hash = self.w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)ainId": self.w3.eth.chain_id,
            "gasPrice": int(self.w3.eth.gas_price),
            "from": self.account.address,
            "nonce": self.w3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.account.address),
        }
    print(tx)
    transaction = this_contract.constructor().buildTransaction(
        tx
    )
   
    signed_txn = self.w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=self.account.key)
    print("Deploying Contract!")
    tx_hash = self.w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```